# How to line up entries when using cftchapternumwidth in memoir document?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm using `cftchapternumwidth` and `cftchapteraftersnum` to insert some spacing between the section numbering and titles in the table of contents of a memoir document. It works great except that it turns out the Bibliography section at the end is not indented because it does not have a section number. See example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{\quad}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{8em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Alpha}
\chapter{Bravo}
\chapter{Charlie}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

And the .bib file:

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
```

If it's relevant, I'm actually using BibTeX, but embedding makes this example shorter. Anyway, the output:

[image: output]

How do I line up the Bibliography section with the rest of the chapters in the ToC?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to fix this, is to alter the way the bibliography is added to the toc. This solution is for `memoir`s own version of `thebibliography` it may be overwritten by other packages.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@memb@bchap}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}%
  \bibmark
  \ifnobibintoc\else
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}%
  \fi
  \prebibhook}
\makeatother
```

I added the `\numberline{}`